# ¿Por qué me da Syntax Error cuando cierro todas las funciones y el php?

Tags: php, mysql

Me da este error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\aloysia\productos.php on line 28  >

El código que tengo es este:

```html
<?php
require_once('config.php'); //hacemos referencia a las variables de conexión
$conexion = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE); //Conectamos a la Base de Datos
$consulta = '';

if( $conexion->connect_errno )
{
 echo 'Error en la conexión';
 exit;
}

//Función que realiza la consulta a la Base de datos
function laConsulta()
{
 global $conexion, $consulta;
 $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM productosima ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($r-mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
        ?>
             <div class="producto">
                <div class="name_producto"><?=$r['name']?>"/></div> 
                <div><img class="img_producto" src="productosima/<?=$r^['imagen']?>"/></div>
                <span class="precio"><?-$r['price']?><?/span>   
            </div>  
 return $conexion->query($sql);

}
}
?>
```

Es una conexión **MySQL**. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, creo que te falta un `<?php` en la linea de `return $conexion->query($sql);`

Comment: seguro que esto esta bien escrito `($r-mysqli_fetch_array($q)`?

Comment: probaré el <?php y creo que si que esta mal escrito creo que es ($sql)

Comment: Me sale la pantalla en blanco, eso que significa?